# qt QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory блокирует работу сокета

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, tcp, modal

У меня есть сокет, он находиться в отдельном классе и запускает в отдельном потоке. Он принимает данные и в окно main отправляет их, там они идут на форму. Проблема в том, что при вызове строки:

```
preIn = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Open Directory"), "/home", QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly | QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
```

из другого окна Settings, открывается модальное окно, которое блокирует отображение данный, принятых через сокет.

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы QFileDialog не блокировал принятие данных в сокете?

---

ДОБАВИЛ: код

```
void draw::sockReady(){

if(socket->waitForConnected(500))
{
    socket->waitForReadyRead(500);

    Data = socket->readAll();
    if(Data != ""){

        qDebug() << Data;

        emit emitSocket(Data);

    }
}
```

}

Для этого использую:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockReady()));
```

---

Новое добавление создание отдельного потока для сокета:

это код draw.cpp:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEventLoop>

#include "draw.h"


draw::draw()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(sockDisc()));

    //Соединяемся через TCP
    socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 8000);

}

draw::~draw()
{
    socket->disconnectFromHost();
    socket->close();
}

//Отсоединение
void draw::sockDisc()
{
    socket->deleteLater();
}

//Ф-ция получения данных и отправка их в главное окно
void draw::sockReady(){

    if(socket->waitForConnected(500))
    {
        socket->waitForReadyRead(500);

        Data = socket->readAll();
        if(Data != ""){

            qDebug() << Data;

            emit emitSocket(Data);

        }
    }
}

void draw::run(){

    qDebug() << "draw: Закончить выполнение потока";
}
```

---

Теперь код draw.h:

```
#ifndef DRAW_H
#define DRAW_H

#include <QThread>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class draw : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    draw();
    ~draw();

    void run();
    
    QTcpSocket* socket;
    QByteArray Data;

public slots:
    void sockDisc();
    void sockReady();

signals:
    void emitSocket(QByteArray);

private:


};

#endif // DRAW_H
```

Запуск делаю через main:     //Запускаем поток для соединения сокета1
myDraw.start();

Comment: Вы проверили, что блокируется именно прием? Из Вашего описания мне показалось, что скорее блокируется отображение при открытии модального окна.

Comment: Внизу в окне "Вывод приложения" не отображаются данные. А логика такая - есть данные отображаем через qDebug их. Данные не отображаются, поэтому думаю, что блокируется именно запись в сокет. В целом какие есть мысли, чтобы сделать работу сокета?

Comment: А сокет - какой? Хотя даже через qDebug я не уверен, что будут выводиться полученные данные. Мне кажется, модальное окно просто не отдаст управление тому коду, где расположен qDebug, пока его не закроют. Хотя тут я могу ошибаться

Comment: Использую QTcpSocket. Ну у меня получается, что не срабатывает: connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockReady()));.
Внутри этого Слота и есть принятие данных. Возможно модальное окно и блокирует, но после его закрытия, все равно работа не продолжается.

Comment: Посмотрите, в описании добавил код. Может есть мыли как сделать, чтобы окно не блокировало место с qDebug или хотя бы после закрытия окна можно было использовать то место? Сейчас даже после закрытия диалогового модального окна, место с qDebug не удается использовать. У вас есть мысли?

Comment: Уберите вызовы `waitForConnected` и `waitForReadyRead` из сокета - раз сокет вызвался, значит вы уже соединились и уже пришли какие-то данные. После `emit emitSocket(data)` попробуйте добавить строку `QCoreApplication::processEvents();`, что должно помочь при модальности, хотя и без этого вызова должно работать - модальность блокирует только ввод со стороны пользователя, но не передачу данных сигнал-слотами. QThread вы неправильно используете, да он вам и не нужен.

Comment: поток нужен. Но вот поток закрывается очень быстро

Comment: Убрал waitForConnected и waitForReadyRead  и добавил QCoreApplication::processEvents(); При этом все повторяется, есть идеи что еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все ожидаемо. Читаем в документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html

> On Windows, the dialog will spin a blocking modal event loop that will not dispatch any QTimers, and if parent is not nullptr then it will position the dialog just below the parent's title bar.

То есть, в случае Windows, диалоговое окно блокирует очередь событий. И, естественно, ничего не будет срабатывать. Даже таймер.

Что делать? по классике - использовать отдельный поток для сети.

Comment: Так я и использую отдельный поток для принятия данных сокета, как теперь быть?

Comment: и этот сокет посылает сигналы в главный?

Comment: а главный поток не принимает сигналы - он заблокирован. И поэтому ничего не увидите.

Comment: Какое может быть решение в таком случае? Пытался сделать это окно немодальным, но без результата. Как вы думаете как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: посмотрел в код детальнее. У Вас прилетает сигнал "readyRead" (то есть сокет готов к чтению. А Вы зачем то ждете пока он подключится и а потом ещё ждете данных... странно это. Но у меня есть подозрение, что сокет все так не в дополнительном потоке, тогда все стает на свои места

Comment: Посмотрите, я добавил код создания этого потока. Я все сделал как надо? Он работает в отдельном потоке или нет? Как вы думаете?

Comment: Унаследовав draw от QThread Вы не перенесли сокет в поток. Там все несколько сложнее. Но если дело, все же, в модальности, то это не поможет. А если нет - то я пока не понимаю, в чем причина проблем.

Comment: Не очень понимаю как в таком случае можно сделать - вызов того модального окна, чтобы оно было не модальным. Вы знаете?

Comment: Давайте посмотрим на Ваш поток. Вы переопределили run, где просто выводите текст и все. А теперь откроем [документацию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) и узнаем, что как только функция run завершается, поток умирает. То есть, очень быстро.

Comment: Как правильно использовать мой поток?

Comment: ну как минимум я для начала выбросил бы этот run. Реализация по умолчанию использует exec, который запускает очередь обработки событий, собственно, что Вам и нужно.

Comment: То есть я убираю run, и мой запуск будет не myDraw.start(); а myDraw.exec() верно?

Comment: нет, все равно start.

Comment: Выполнил теперь не работает connectToHost

Comment: Ваш класс сокета создается в конструкторе обертки для потока. Но поток ещё не создан и класс сокета принадлежит главному потоку. У потока есть сигнал started, который собственно и испускается, когда поток запустился - переносите в него создание сокета.